# How to show arraylist one by one in AsyncTask?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask

I am using arraylist to store the data from cursor selecting and return to the AsyncTask in main activity. For showing the result one by one, I put the for loop in onPostExecute. But there is nothing shown on the screen. When I put the try and catch at the first begging at onPostExecute, debug cannot be executed. So whats going wrong with the AsyncTask code and return arraylist code?

AsyncTask:

```
protected class tryconnect extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        EditText city=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.city_address);
        String   mycity=city.getText().toString();
        EditText street=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.street_address);
        String   mystreet=street.getText().toString();
        EditText postcode=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.postcode_address);
        String   mypostcode=postcode.getText().toString();
        EditText number=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.number_address);
        String   mynumber=number.getText().toString();
        String   ReservedState="Free";
        List<String> result=dbHelper1.select1(ReservedState, mycity, mystreet, mypostcode);
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                String b=result.get(i);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String baseURL="https://fontys.nedapparking.com/so.xml?Ln=adminfontys&Pw=f0nty589&Cm=1&Fm=A&PrkLt=1&Bay=";
                //c is the retrieving result from reservation table
                String a=b;
                StringBuilder URL=new StringBuilder(baseURL);
                URL.append(a);
                String fullURL=URL.toString();
                try{
                    URL website=new URL(fullURL);
                    //getting xmlreader to parse data
                    SAXParserFactory spf=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                    SAXParser sp=spf.newSAXParser();
                    XMLReader xr=sp.getXMLReader();

                    HandlingXMLStuff doingWork=new HandlingXMLStuff();
                    xr.setContentHandler(doingWork);
                    try{
                        xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    information=doingWork.getInformation();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
            Message.message(FragmentHandler.this,information);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
}
```

return arraylist :

```
public List<String> select1 (String ReservedState, String mycity, String mystreet, String mypostcode){
    ReservedState="Free";
    SQLiteDatabase Database1=dbHelper1.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns={DbHelper1.KEY_ID1,DbHelper1.KEY_RESERVEDSTATE, DbHelper1.KEY_GEOGRAPHICALLOCATION,DbHelper1.KEY_CITY,DbHelper1.KEY_POSTCODE,DbHelper1.KEY_STREET};
    Cursor cursor=Database1.query(DbHelper1.TABLE_NAME_1,columns, DbHelper1.KEY_RESERVEDSTATE+"='"+ReservedState+"' AND "+DbHelper1.KEY_CITY+"='"+mycity+"' AND "+DbHelper1.KEY_POSTCODE+"='"+mypostcode+"' AND "+DbHelper1.KEY_STREET+"='"+mystreet+"'",null,null,null,null);
    StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
    List<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        int index1=cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper1.KEY_ID1);
        String id=cursor.getString(index1);
        al.add(id);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    return al;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, lose the try and catch clauses, unless something in your code throws an exception

Second of all add a check at the start of `onPostExecute()` to check if `result` is null

Third, you're returning null from your `doInBackground()` while your should be returning your list to be processed

Change this

```
List<String> result=dbHelper1.select1(ReservedState, mycity, mystreet, mypostcode);
return null;
```

To something like that

```
return dbHelper1.select1(ReservedState, mycity, mystreet, mypostcode);
```

Comment: The toast shows, but only one. It is supposed to be two. How can I check how many strings are there in the arraylist?

Comment: maybe do something like:
Log.d("List size", String.valueOf(result.size());
or debug to check the list size

Comment: I checked the debug value window and found there was only one value under the arraylist. So is there anything wrong with the arraylist code? Thank you.

Comment: your query code looks fine, make sure you actually have more than one value in the database your're querying

Comment: and both of them meets the query clause you're specifying ?

Comment: Yes. they are the same.